# JQuery - search through column, when text changes add new row before

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a dynamic method of searching through a column and when a value changes a new row should be inserted.

Consider the following table:

```
<table id="testTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Letter</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">A</td>
      <td>110</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">A</td>
      <td>99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">A</td>
      <td>106</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">A</td>
      <td>120</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">C</td>
      <td>103</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When it encounters a change such as going from 'A' to 'C' in the parent class, I would like a row inserted before 'C' or whatever value maybe different from the one before. I have sort of started with this to capture some data but have not gotten far:

```
$('#' + value + ' .parent').each(function () {
        var firstVal = $(this).html();
        var secondVal = $(this).next().html();
        if(firstVal == secondVal) {
        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().after('</tr><tr><td class="sub0">Sub Total</td></tr>');
        }
    })
```

Please see my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khemikal/q4gq2u2c/)

Comment: Actually, you did it. You forgot to add (document).ready . check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/q4gq2u2c/2/

Comment: That is actually adding a new row regardless if it encounters a change, for example subtotal row should not be inserted until it encounters a different value, for example it should only be showing once, before C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var lastVal = '';
$('#testTable .parent').each(function () {
        var currentVal = $(this).html();
        if(currentVal != lastVal) {
            $(this).parent().before('</tr><tr><td class="sub0">Sub Total</td></tr>');
            lastVal = currentVal;
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q4gq2u2c/4/)

Answer (score 1):

all you have to do is compare the values and [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) the row like this:

```
let prev = "";
$('.parent').each(function() {
    let test = $(this).text();
    if(test != prev && prev != ""){
    //$(this).prepend('<tr><td class="separator"><hr></td></tr>');//add it to the same row...
    $(this).parent().before('<tr><td colspan="2" class="separator"><hr></td></tr>');
    }
    prev = test;
    //console.log(test);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight change in your code will do the needful.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lastVal = '';
  $('#testTable .parent').each(function() {
    var currentVal = $(this).html();
    if (currentVal != lastVal) {
      $(this).parent().before('</tr><tr><td class="sub0">Sub Total</td></tr>');
      lastVal = currentVal;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="testTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Letter</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">A</td>
      <td>110</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">A</td>
      <td>99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">A</td>
      <td>106</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">A</td>
      <td>120</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">C</td>
      <td>103</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var perent = $('.parent');
$.each(perent, function(i, y) {
  if ($(perent[i]).html() != $(perent[i + 1]).html()) {
    $(this).parent().after('</tr><tr><td class="sub0">Sub Total</td></tr>');
  }


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="testTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Letter</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">A</td>
      <td>110</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">A</td>
      <td>99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">A</td>
      <td>106</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">A</td>
      <td>120</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">C</td>
      <td>103</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```